# Generating a list from several dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have several data frames named data1, data2, data3, data4, ... data100. How can I store them in a list so that I'm able to plot them with a for loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could join them in a list like `l = [data1, data2, ...]` and then iterating through that list you could plot each dataframe

Comment: @AntonProtopopov Thanks, perhaps a better question was how to create that list of variables when having a large number of dataframes ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is a symptom of using numbered variables.

You can avoid the problem entirely by using a list of DataFrames (e.g. `data`)
instead of using numbered variables (`data1`, `data2`, `data3`, etc.)

The trick is to avoid creating the numbered variables in the first place.
If you have code of the form

```
data1 = ...
data2 = ...
data3 = ...
```

Try to replace it with something like

```
data = []
data.append(...)
data.append(...)
data.append(...)
```

or better yet, use a list comprehension or a for-loop to define `data`. For more specific suggestions, show us the code that defines the numbered variables.

Then you could loop over the DataFrames with

```
for df in data:
    df.plot(...)
```

---

If for some reason you can not prevent (someone else?) from defining the numbered variables, then you could use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) (or [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals)) to access the numbered variables programmatically:

```
g = globals()
data = [g['data{}'.format(i)] for i in range(1, 101)]
```

`globals()` returns a dictionary whose keys are string representations of names
in the global namespace. The associated values are the Python objects bound to
those names. Thus, you can use `globals()` to look up the values bound to
variable names based on the string representation of those variable names.
Use `locals()` if the variable names are defined in the local (rather than global) namespace.

Still, try to avoid using numbered variables. This use of `globals()` is merely a workaround for trouble someone else is causing. Using string formatting to look up variable names is not great programming style when simple integer indexing (of a list) should suffice. The best solution is to convince that someone to stop using numbered variables and to instead deliver the values in a list.

Comment: The problem is that I have no control over how the data is stored. I agree having a list and plotting from that list is reasonable but generating that list is a problem if the number of dataframes are large enough.